# dfsql - embedded count statement returning total instead of where condition

Tags: r, statistics

```
sqldf(' select avg(mpg), avg(hp), gear, count("select count() from mtcars where 
carb==4") from mtcars group by gear')
```

I have code similar to what is above in my program.  I am trying to write a query so that the Count information is a count only of how many cars contain carb=4.  However, instead of getting a count of carb=4 in this field, I am getting the total number of cars in each group by - gear.

Can someone show me how to code this in sqldf specifically?  I realize that I could write this as perhaps a double group by with gear & carb, but that is not what I am after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
> sqldf("select gear, avg(mpg), avg(hp), sum(carb=4) from mtcars group by gear")
  gear avg(mpg)  avg(hp) sum(carb=4)
1    3 16.10667 176.1333           5
2    4 24.53333  89.5000           4
3    5 21.38000 195.6000           1
```